# How to change the width of a pattern brush in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, brush

[image]

The upper right orange balloon is the result of applying a pattern brush that I want to achieve.

[image]

Although it has anchor points in the places of the 2 red circles, my blue pattern brush applied to a curved stroke has no indentations.

I wonder how to make a path like the orange balloon.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern brushes are susceptible to the Width tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>). Select this tool and drag over your stroke to add a width point and change the width of the brush there.

If you add three width points, you should be able to achieve what you want: one width point on the anchor that makes the stroke real thin, and one on each side of the anchor, a bit removed, to reset the stroke to its default width.